# ServiceStack Redis client Get<T>(key) removes quotes from string data

Tags: redis, double-quotes, servicestack.redis

I am using ServiceStack.Redis library to work with Redis. To start with, I have implemented [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1120038/A-simple-Csharp-cache-component-using-Redis-as-pro) solution. The get/set methods work fine for plain text/string.

Now when I save a string with quotes (with escape char), it saves properly (I verify the same in redis-cli). But the Get method returns string having all the double quotes removed.

For example saving this string - **"TestSample"** is saved and get as expected. Also, 
saving **"TestSample \"with\" \"quotes\""** is fine and shows same in redis-cli. But the output of Get method becomes **"TestSample with quotes"**

```
     public bool SetDataInCache<T>(string cacheKey, T cacheData)
    {

        try
        {
            using (_redisClient = new RedisClient(_cacheConfigs.RedisHost))
            {                   
                _redisClient.As<T>().SetValue(cacheKey, cacheData, new TimeSpan(0,0,300));
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public T GetDataFromCacheByType<T>(string cacheKey)
    {
        T retVal = default(T);

        try
        {
            using (_redisClient = new RedisClient(_cacheConfigs.RedisHost))
            {
                if (_redisClient.ContainsKey(cacheKey))
                {
                    var wrapper = _redisClient.As<T>();
                    retVal = wrapper.GetValue(cacheKey);
                }
                return retVal;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            return retVal;
        }
```

### }

Usage:

```
   cacheObj.SetDataInCache("MyKey1","TestSample");
   cacheObj.SetDataInCache("MyKey2","TestSample \"with\" \"quotes\"");

   string result1 = Convert.ToString(cacheObj.GetDataFromCacheByType<string>("MyKey1"));
   string result2 = Convert.ToString(cacheObj.GetDataFromCacheByType<string>("MyKey2"));
```

Actual : "TestSample with quotes"

Expected : "TestSample \"with\" \"quotes\""

Answer (score 1):

The Typed Generic API is only meant for creating a generic Redis Client for serializing complex types. If you're implementing a generic cache you should use the `IRedisClient` APIs instead, e.g:

```
_redisClient.Set(cacheKey, cacheData, new TimeSpan(0,0,300));
```

Then retrieve back with:

```
var retVal = _redisClient.Get<T>(cacheKey);
```

Alternatively for saving strings or if you want to serialize the POCOs yourself you can use the `IRedisClient` SetValue/GetValue string APIs, e.g:

```
_redisClient.SetValue(cacheKey, cacheData.ToJson());
var retVal = _redisClient.GetValue(cacheKey).FromJson<T>();
```

> Note: calling `IRedisClient.ContainsKey()` performs an additional unnecessary Redis I/O operation, since you're returning `default(T)` anyway you should just call `_redisClient.Get<T>()` which returns the default value for non-existing keys.

Comment: I was facing the same problem. But I was using redisClient.Get<string>(key) to get value and double quotes was being removed. From your question I got a hint and tried redisClient.GetValue(key) and it worked for me. thanks for posting this question. +1 for question.